# Cross-Platform Project Templates are Not in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Cross-Platform Project Templates in `Visual Studio 2015` are Not in `Visual Studio 2017`. How To Add templates in `VS2017`?

[image]

[image]